# Following up using comments

Tags: discussion, comments

I've been in the situation that I answered questions with more than one-liners, and the original poster didn't follow up at all (commenting what was wrong with the answers provided by me and others, etc.), and didn't accept an answer (not mine, not others').

If I'm confident with my answers, I added comments to their question, suggesting they add to their questions, explaining why the answers don't satisfy them, or that they should accept an answer.

I've received a few accepted answers this way. It seems many just forget about their questions. Reminding them to accept or follow up on the answers improves question/answer quality and prevents them from being bumped up unnecessarily. Otoh, they might just accept to shut me up.

Is this abuse of the comment functionality? It's not mentioned in the `/privileges` explanation, so I'm asking here.

Comment: An example of question(s) would be helpful.

Comment: @KronoS: My answers were accepted [here](http://superuser.com/questions/199578/how-to-use-time-machine-with-file-vault), [here](http://superuser.com/questions/191424/how-to-disable-inputing-characters-like-aaa-by-default-in-os-x-i-just-want-to-si) and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/191141/change-function-key-behavior-is-osx-but-only-for-some-f-keys). If there are multiple answers, I don't promote my own (at least not imo). I got no reaction [here](http://superuser.com/questions/199891), probably due to the user being rather inactive.

Comment: Turns out those *are* oneliners. Hm... early onset Alzheimer's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this abuse of the comment functionality ?

I don't think so. The comments box are provided specifcally for this - for follow ups /clarifications and for the odd nudge.

Comment: As long as it remains 'the odd nudge' and doesn't become a spammy habit ;-)

Comment: Of course @Ivo ;)

Comment: Good enough for me to know it's not generally frowned upon. Thanks!